# Can a tweet against me, stating my name be bad for employment in the future?

Tags: recruitment

there is a tweet that's says to not hire me on twitter linking a tweet of mine where I was offensed and say something impulsively, when I saw this tweet I instantly removed mine and I apologized. 
But will there be consequences later (I'm still a student and don't plan on working until 4 years) ?

Thanks

Comment: If your tweet was "i rape childrens lol", and you were applying for a writer position, than it might be bad. Because of the grammar errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sure depends on what you said, but generally, I'd say no. As long as you can do the job, I really don't care who said what on twitter half a decade ago. Who knows if twitter is still in business by that time. I will hire you based on your skills on the job and your personal attitude in the interview.

But employers can hire (or even fire in some countries) you based on whatever criteria they see fit. So maybe putting your twitter account name on the application might not be your best move, because I cannot see any benefit.

Comment: *I will hire you based on your skills on the job and your personal attitude in the interview.* But if you have to filter 100 reasonably-qualified applicants down to 1 job offer, the guy who tweeted something idiotic (or any other faux-pas) isn't even getting to an interview, nor will you spend any time evaluating his skills.

Comment: @ExactaBox If I get 100 applications, I will not even *try* to find out each applicants social media accounts and go through their last 4 years of posts. That's 400 man-years of silly talk, 9gag, photos of peoples lunch and cat content. I don't have time for that, I have a job to do.

Comment: But your HR dept might. Legal might require you to do it. Or your company might hire an outside service that specializes in reviewing social media. Or you might, if the applicant makes it down to the final 4, for example.  Your answer states, "It sure depends on what you said" which implies that if this person is about to be hired, you will have seen the negative tweet.

Comment: @ExactaBox I have been part of the hiring process of the companies I worked for for more than a decade and none of them did check social media because it would not provide any benefit. If your experiences in your company differ, feel free to write an alternative answer with your experiences. "it depends" meant that if the social media had real world consequences (for example you were legally fired from your last job because you talked bad about it on FB) then I will get to know through normal means like references.

Answer (score 3):

On average, [350,000 tweets are sent every minute](http://www.internetlivestats.com/twitter-statistics/).  The odds of a prospective employer seeing it *today* are low unless somebody knows where you're applying and is actively campaigning against you.  The odds of a prospective employer seeing it *four years from now* are vanishingly small.

This is all assuming it didn't go viral or make the news or something.  But even if it did, do you know off the top of your head who the guy was who tweeted the raid on Osama bin Laden in real time?  It was all over the news just a few years ago and it was an event of international significance; how many people remember *his* name?

While you should always be careful online because you never know what indiscretions will come back to bite you later, one second-hand tweet doesn't seem like something to worry about.